# How to convert string with TLF format into TextFlow in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, tlf

I used TextConverter to convert a TextFlow in Flex to String to store it in my Database. How to convert that string back to TextFlow in order to display in Rich Text format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yourRichTextArea.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(yourStoredDataBaseString)